# Django mobile and full site redirects

Tags: django, mobile, jquery-mobile, django-middleware

I've been searching for a while on Google and haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for and decided to ask everyone here.

I've got a full site and mobile version of the site (one page jQuery Mobile file).

In theory what I would like is to check the incoming request for a possible mobile device (I can already do this) and redirect to the mobile site.  On the mobile site the user can click a link to the full site that sets a cookie and won't redirect that user back to the mobile site (even though they will meet that condition with every request with their device).

All that I have been able to find is about how to check every request for mobile/desktop device and change the template accordingly.  Which isn't what I need to do in this situation.  It's a completely different template for the mobile and desktop versions.

Any ideas or solutions that may help in this situation?

UPDATE 1:

So I've tried implementing this and I am having some weird issues/problems.  Here is my Middleware (listed last on the Middleware list in the settings)

```
class mobile_check(object):

def process_request(self,request):
    if mobileBrowser(request) and not request.session.get('view_full'):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts.views.mobile_django'))
```

Here's the view to handle when they click the full site link in jQuery Mobile.

```
def mobile_fullsite(request):
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

request.session['view_full'] = True
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts.views.index'))
```

In my head this should work fine but it doesn't.  It hits the mobile_fullsite view from the link and the url changes from .../mobile/  to .../fullsite/  Yet it still looks like jQuery mobile with some stuff from the redirected pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`django-mobile` has many of the features you are looking for. THey are implemented in a couple different parts.  The first one detects the mobile user agent.  The second one renders the template corresponding to that (either full site or mobile site).  In addition it allows a user to select which version they want to see (with a GET) request.  https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile

Please check it out, even if it doesn't have everything you need it has a wide following and i'm sure it will be able to offer you some code.

If your use case is a little different you can easily use django's sessions framework (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) to keep direct the user accordingly.

```
# user asks to view full site
request.session['view_full'] = True
```

then in your middle ware when checking for mobile user agent, psuedo below

```
if is_mobile and not request.session.get('view_full'):
  # they have mobile device and haven't request to see full site!~
  # Just check that they don't have a preference for viewing full site^
```

Comment: From looking at this though am I correct in assuming that it expects a mobile version of each of my pages (and therefore just serves a mobile flavor instead of the regular desktop flavor)?  If that's the case then that isn't quite what I'm needing.   As to your second idea, would it be better to use the session framework or cookies?

Comment: @Fernker seesions are using cookies to store you session id! But you can configure sessions to store data in encrypted cookies if you want.  Sessions is just a nice simple abstraction to store data in a variety of places. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-engine

Answer (score 0):

You might want a full redirect rather than just changing the template. Look at [django.http.HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects)

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# test for mobile device here
# test for full site session variable here
fullSiteRequest = request.session.get('User_Wants_Full_Site', False)

if mobileDevice and not fullSiteRequest:
    return HttpReponseRedirect('mobile.mysite.com')

# continue onto your regular site
```

ed. To reflect my comment below.

Comment: Yeah I have already implemented a mobile redirect, the problem is when the mobile user (now on the mobile page) wants to go back to the full site.  Your solution isn't a full solution for that.

Comment: While I didn't explicitly code it, it would be fairly simple to check whether the user has requested to go to the full site by either checking for a cookie or session variable in the if statement.

Comment: I've added an update, as adding what needs to be added isn't going as simply as I would expect.